# Fade DIV with cool animation

Tags: jquery

I am fading a DIV slowly,

```
$(ele).fadeIn('slow');
```

How can i create a very good animation along with the fadeIn to show real animation power of jquery

Comment: what is, for you, a "real animation" ?

Comment: anything that creates the 'wow' effect a little more than simple fadein..It could be anything..any example would do..I just need to show how powerful jquery is so that we can start using it

Comment: Did you try the special <blink> tag? That is soooo cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also check out [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) as this allows you to animate colours too or read [this article](http://devsnippets.com/jquery-posts/20-jquery-plugins-for-unforgettable-user-experience.html)  about plugins for unforgetable user experiences.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of animation are you looking for? You could [slideDown()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown), [slideUp()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideUp#speedcallback) or use [animate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback) and define your own

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple animations in jquery really easily:

```
/*you can hide your item with the css property first*/

<style>
 #id_of_what_want_to_animate{display:none;height:1px;}
</style>
```

then reveal it with jquery

```
//target the item that triggers the animation
$('#clickthis').click(function() {
   //when clicked animate whatever you want, the 5000 is the duration of the animation in
   //milliseconds inside the curly braces you can animate css properties   
  $('#id_of_what_want_to_animate').animate({opacity: 1,height: '200px'},5000,function() {
    //run something else when your animation complete.
  });
});
```

you can refer to jquery's detailed documentation at:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/